# парсинг видеоплеера - не работает fullscreen

Tags: парсер

Разработал парсинг видеоплеера(точнее проекта онлайн-тв). Можно было заморочиться с вытягиванием лишь потоков из m3u8, но тогда я бы не смог подключить программу тв-передач или бы пришлось очень затянуть старт проекта.
В общем сделал парсинг, всё работает отлично кроме некоторых некритичных скриптов, но вот кнопка на весь экран не срабатывает из плеера. Т.е. все функции плеера работают, кроме функции fullscreen.
В источнике (исходный проект онлайн-ТВ) fullscreen в плеере работает.
Как я понимаю реализовать функционал fullscreen не представляется возможным?
Для наглядности:
source: smotret.tv
выход: krasnovosti.ru/tv